# Python - multiprocessing - processes became zombies

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For a couple weeks I have been trying to solve a problem with a multiprocessing module in python (2.7.x)

**Idea:**

Lets have Message Queue (RabbitMQ in our case). Create a listener on that queue and on the message spawn task which will process that message.

**Problem:**

Everything works fine, but after a couple hundred tasks, some sub-processes became zombies which is the main problem.

We have also some limitation (such as max number of tasks per machine) - which in the end leads that the machine stops processing any task.

**Current implementation:**

I created minimal code which should explain our approach

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Process
import signal
from threading import Lock


class Task(Process):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(Task, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        # ignore sigchild signals in subprocess
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_DFL)
        self.do_job() # long job there
        pass

    def do_job(self):
        # very long job
        pass


class MQListener(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []
        self.tasks_lock = Lock()
        self.register_signal_handler()
        mq = RabbitMQ()
        mq.listen("task_queue", self.on_message)

    def register_signal_handler(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, self.on_signal_received)

    def on_signal_received(self, *_):
        self._check_existing_processes()

    def on_message(self, message):
        # ack message and create task
        task = Task(message)
        with self.tasks_lock:
            self.tasks.append(task)
            task.start()
        pass

    def _check_existing_processes(self):
        """
        go over all created task, if some is not alive - remove them from tasks collection
        """
        try:
            with self.tasks_lock:
                running_tasks = []
                for w in self.tasks:
                    if not w.is_alive():
                        w.join()
                    else:
                        running_tasks.append(w)

                self.tasks = running_tasks
        except Exception:
            # log
            pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MQListener()
```

I'm quite open to use some library for that - if you can recommend some, that will be great as well.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase the last sentence. Questions asking for tool/library recommendation tend to attract spam. Such questions are also considered offtopic.

Comment: If you are already have RabbitMQ installed then you could try [`celery` to run tasks in multiple Python processes](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps).

Comment: If your code manipulates `SIGCHLD` then it is your responsibility to reap the child processes. Does `w.join()` call `waitpid()` analog eventually?

Answer (score 3):

Using SIGCHLD to catch child processes termination has quite many gotchas. The signal handler is run asynchronously and multiple SIGCHLD calls might get aggregated.

In short is better not to use it as long as you're not really aware of how it works.

Your program has, as well, another issue: what happens if you get 10000 messages at once? You'll spawn 10000 processes altogether and kill your machine.

You could use a [process Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) and let it handle all these issues for you.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


class MQListener(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = Pool()
        self.rabbitclient = RabbitMQ()

    def new_message(self, message):
        self.pool.apply_async(do_job, args=(message, ))

    def run(self):
        self.rabbitclient.listen("task_queue", self.new_message)


app = MQListener()
app.run()
```

Comment: thanks for reply. In general, there is no problem with lot of messages, since there is mechanism, which simple requeue message when there is no capacity (subprocess limit).

Comment: I guessed so, but a system is robust when all its component are so ;)